# Display row from panle grid on new line

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using a datagrid to display row dynamically from panelgrid. It works fine except the layout is not good. It displays the following row side by side instead on new line. Anyone know how to display a new row on a new line ? I tried to use `<br/>` tag, but it's not working.

```
  <p:dataGrid style="border:10px;" value="#{TestComponent.list}" var="x">
        <p:panelGrid style="width:1250px;">
            <p:row>
                <p:column colspan="1">1.1</p:column>
                <p:column colspan="2">
                    <h:outputText value="#{x.Description}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column colspan="4">
                    <h:inputTextarea rows="10" cols="40"
                        value="#{x.Justification}" required="false" label="Justification" />
                </p:column>
            </p:row>    
        </p:panelGrid>
        <br/>
    </p:dataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new line, you must create a new `<p:row>` tag.

Example:

```
<p:panelGrid>
   <p:row>
      <p:column>Row 1/Column 1</p:column>
      <p:column>Row 1/Column 2</p:column>
   </p:row>
   <p:row>
      <p:column>Row 2/Column 1</p:column>
      <p:column>Row 2/Column 2</p:column>
   </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of things done wrong.  The datagrid by itself puts childeren next to eachother in colums (default = 3 , see the docs http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataGrid.xhtml). So 3 panelgrids next to eachother (so three rows next to eachother). Setting the columns to 1 will makr it work.  Additionally, a colspan does nothing if there are not multiple rows like in the example @pellizon mentiones.

Comment: So you are saying that it's not possible to do this?(Display each row on a line)

Comment: No, I (tried to) explain why you get what you see. (did you try setting columns to 1?)

Answer (score 0):

Manage to do it. It have to specify the number of columns in my datagrid.